# Sticky labels for random sequence

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I’m new to VBA. What I need to do is sticky labels like it is shown in picture [image] for different projects. Such text [XXX….] in Word will be replaced by the macro in Excel which I found in internet (see below) depending on project. Text without brackets XXX… will remain the same for each sticky label. I have such Excel part of the process where source information is placed:[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1wXA.jpg)

However, I have 2 special situations/issues with the text which I cannot solve:

1. Depending on project, I need different amount of sticky labels. Sometimes it is 30, sometimes 70. So, I would like to modify the code I have to implement a special field in Excel where I could input the exact value of the labels which I need. How can I do this?
2. The biggest red letter [X] will be replaced based on random sequence of A or B. So we have e.g. 70 sticky labels and random sequence is 1-A, 2-B, 3-A etc. until 70 (but it could be another sequence for next project). How can I do this?

I don’t ask for the code for that task (but if you are so kind I would really appreciate it). At least I would like to know the way I can do this in Excel VBA in order to get sticky labels in Word.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Generator()
    Dim ObWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.document
    Dim file As String
    Set ob1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    f_r = Selection.Row
    stb = Selection.Column
    f_c = Selection.CurrentRegion.Columns(Selection.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Column
    path_f = ThisWorkbook.Path
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.docx;*.doc), *docx;*.doc")
    If Dir(file) = Empty Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        With ObjWord
            .Visible = True
            .Documents.Open Filename:=file
            Set objDoc = .ActiveDocument
        End With
        With objDoc.Range
            For j = 1 To f_c
                isk_zn = ob1.Cells(1, j)
                zamen_zn = ob1.Cells(f_r, j)
                .Find.ClearFormatting
                .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
                With .Find
                    .Text = isk_zn
                    .Replacement.Text = zamen_zn
                    .Forward = True
                    .wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                End With
                .Find.Execute Replace:=2
            Next j
            FName = ob1.Cells(f_r, stb)
            objDoc.SaveAs Filename:=path_f & "\" & FName
            objDoc.Close
            ObjWord.Quit
        End With
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        Set ObjWord = Nothing
        ob1.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Please take a moment to read the content in the site's [help] about asking questions on Stack Overflow. Notice that questions should be very specifically targeted - about a *single* problem AND that they should provide full detailed information about how to reproduce the environment the question is about. Break down your problem into smaller bits - you're allowed to ask multiple questions. The code you have should work with the Word document you describe: it obviously does not. If you don't understand the code well enough to run it on your sample document then that's where you need to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA to generate labels from data in Excel as this is a built-in feature.

Here is information about how to:

- [**Create and print mailing labels for an address list in Excel**](https://support.office.com/article/create-and-print-mailing-labels-for-an-address-list-in-excel-d9ae0b60-9fd0-4a90-9da9-0ec3a4b011b2)
- [**Print mailing labels**](https://support.office.com/article/print-mailing-labels-276a2cd1-74d2-43d0-ab5a-b90460358ad5) (with Video)

Regardless of whether it's actually addresses that you're trying to print, the process is the same.

---

As for your code, I fixed indentation so it's easier to see what's going on. I'd suggest adding the line `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help "force" you to properly declare and handle your variables, objects, etc.

In your code the following variables are undeclared:

```
ob1, f_r, stb, f_c, path_f, file, ObjWord, j, isk_zn, zamen_zn, FName
```

...and at least one is misspelled (`ObjWord` vs `ObWord`).

**See also:**

- [**Declaring Variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables)

...and **Tutorials**:

- [**Home & Learn VBA Tutorial**](//www.homeandlearn.org/)
- [**Macro Mastery Tutorial**](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-tutorial-1/)
- [**Microsoft's VBA Documentation**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/vba-language-reference)